# Wireframes for Webdesign with tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am searching for information about using tikz to draw wireframes for websites. Is there any particular workflow around? Does somebody know some sort of packages I can use?

Here is [a link](http://graphicdesign.about.com/od/effectivewebsites/ss/wireframes.htm) to explain the term "wireframe".

Comment: Can you lead us to something tangible that you have in mind? Is it related to trees? Google gives diverse results for wireframes (yep, I have no idea what a wireframe is).

Comment: The probability to find a package is null but have you tried to draw a wireframe, it seems easy ?

Comment: Sorry for my offtopic comment. IMHO in this particular case a GUI approach seems better. There's a nice opensource tool for drawing diagrams and GUI prototyping called [Pencil Project](http://pencil.evolus.vn/en-US/Home.aspx) which can export to `pdf`. `:)`